# Using tr with a built in argument set

Tags: bash, shell, tr

I have a variable called `charAlpha`. It's purpose is to go through a text document and count alphabetic characters. I am trying to use `tr` and the built in `[:alpha:]` set to get just alphabetic characters. Then I am piping it through `wc -c` to count and get a number that is stored in `charAlpha` and later in the script it will echo the number stored in `charAlpha`. I hope I don't seem like I'm over explaining as I am trying to provide all information needed here. I have done that in the past and I am trying very hard not to do that! Thanks for any help!

I am using bash and editing my script within vim.

I set

```
charAlpha=`tr -dc [:alpha:] < | wc -c`
```

Then I get these two errors:

```
./filestats: command substitution: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
./filestats: command substitution: line 7: `tr -dc [:alpha:] < | wc -c'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<` in your pre-piped command isn't going to give `tr` any input. Hence, it's erroring on the pipe (it expects a source of input).

Comment: @a p Thanks, geeze I'm tired. I added a file and working! Thanks a bunch and sorry for MY confusion!

Comment: @user3347022 shellcheck also suggests quoting `'[:alpha:]'` since it otherwise may expand to files named "a" or "l" in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

The `< |` part is probably your problem, you need a filename between them. Something like (it's normally recommended to use `$(...)` instead of`` `...` ``as well):

```
charAlpha=$(tr -dc [:alpha:] < $myFile | wc -c)
```

Comment: Yea that's what I got from the other answer, I realized I didn't have a file after <. No sleep will do that to you! Thanks a bunch!